# sql server create dynamic columns runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server

in sql server create dynamic query to create columns 
for example

```
    declare @NoOFcolumns int=5
select name, [Col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5]
from
(
  select c.name,
    cr.description,
    r.typeid
  from customers c
  left join rewards r
    on c.id = r.customerid
  left join customerrewards cr
    on r.typeid = cr.typeid
) x
pivot
(
  count(typeid)
  for description in ([Col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5])
) p;
```

then add 5 columns

for eaxmple  @NoOFcolumns int=10
how to add 10 columns by default

Comment: You can easily have dynamic SQL SEELECT command by building your command in a varchar, i.e.  @DYNSQLCOM and using "EXEC sp_executesql @DYNSQLCOM" 
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `distinct` `top (@NoOFcolumns)` from you `customerrewards` tables for generating the dynamic pivot.

You can try using dynamic PIVOT like following.

```
DECLARE @NoOFcolumns int=5

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@NoOFcolumns)  ', ' 
                                 + Quotename([description] ) 
         FROM   customerrewards 
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) =
                 'select *
                        from
                        (
                            select c.name,
                            cr.description,
                            r.typeid
                            from customers c
                            left join rewards r
                            on c.id = r.customerid
                            left join customerrewards cr
                            on r.typeid = cr.typeid
                        ) x
                        pivot
                        (
                            count(typeid)
                            for description in IN ('+@cols+') 
                        ) p;'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Note: I have not executed the query myself, but I feel it should work.

Comment: Maybe even change the select * to select name' + @cols +'

I was about to suggest